# Stack overflow with C list when adding dynamic variables

Tags: c, list, stack-overflow, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm having some trouble with a school project.

What I need to do is fairly simple, I just have to add some data to the list.
I would normally know how to do so, but the fact that the memory allocation is dynamic has confused me.

So here's the list:

```
typedef struct cList {
char *concept; // the concept learned
char *sentence; // the sentence associated with the concept
int timesUsed; //no of times the concept was used to an answer
char learnedFrom[5]; //learned either from "file" or "kbrd"
struct cList *next;
} conceptList;
```

And the function which adds the new data to the list:

```
void insert(char *concept, char *sentence, int timesUsed, char learnedFrom[5]) 
{
    int flag = 0, temp; 

    struct cList *link = (struct cList*) malloc(sizeof(struct cList));

    if(link!=NULL)
    {
        strcpy(link->concept,concept); //this is where the stack overflow happens first.
        strcpy(link->sentence,sentence);
        link->timesUsed = timesUsed;
        strcpy(link->learnedFrom,learnedFrom);

        link->next = head;
        head = link;

        temp = rand()%5;
        if(temp==0)
            printf("3B$ It sure is great to know everything about %s.\n", concept);
        else if(temp==1)
            printf("3B$ This information about %s is quite interesting.", concept);
        else if(temp==2)
            printf("3B$ I have to admit, learning about %s is much more interesting than it seems.", concept);
        else if(temp==3)
            printf("3B$ Learning about %s wasn't even a challenge.", concept);
        else if(temp==4)
            printf("3B$ Wow, learning about %s was so exciting!", concept);
    }
    else
        printf("3B$ Memory not available!!!\n");
}
```

Comment: `strcpy(link->concept,concept);` --> `link->concept = malloc(strlen(concept)+1); strcpy(link->concept, concept);`

Comment: You don't allocate memory for the pointers in the struct. You try to use the memory they point to which leads to *undefined behaviour* which can do anything. Look up `strdup` and remember to free the memory.

Comment: When you allocate the structure it will NOT allocate space for "concept" and "sentence". This means then when you try to write to these locations, it'll crash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After first `malloc`, `concept` member has un-inizialize value.

You need to allocate space for the passed string before to

```
strcpy(link->concept,concept);
```

so you need

```
link->concept = malloc(strlen(concept)+1);
if (link->concept != NULL)
{
    strcpy(link->concept,concept);
}
else
{
    free(link)
    return;
}
```

Same thing for `sentence` member.

Comment: It's just `strdup()`.

Comment: @0andriy if your sdk support it. The proposed solution works always a malloc is available.

Comment: Can you point to at least one which does not in 21st century?

Comment: So, how gcc flags are related to C library? You mean your code will use intrinsics?

Comment: Okay, it looks like you just speculating and there is none existing among often used SDKs. I'm done here, if you wish to change my mind, please, be more precise.

Comment: @0andriy Far be it from me to change your mind: you can continue to code with strdup your whole life. You asked me something, I answered you two main thing: 1) it is a `POSIX` function not `ANSI C`, so not fully portable. 2) It means that not all toolchains/SDKs supportit: for example I (unfortunately) worked with Microchip `C30` where strdup was not supported. In embedded world the use of dynamic allocation is avoided as evil. BTW, as I suggested you, try to compile a simple example, using [tag:gcc],  with `strdup` and compile it using `-std=C11` as parameter and you'll face what I meant.

Comment: @0andriy Lastly: a library function that `malloc`ate something you are in charge to `free` is only bu.....hit. (my personal opinion)

Comment: So what? Cite: *...a lot of compiler people do seem to look to standards more than actual users for guides to do things..."*.

Moreover, how does your point *In embedded world the use of dynamic allocation is avoided as evil.* correlate with  your answer that using `malloc()`?

Comment: @0andriy The malloc is correlated to the OP answer, not to embedded world, where `malloc` is widely available (not in all SDK) because it is `ANSI C`, and for example, forbidden by `MISRA C rule 20.4`. Moreover if I explicitly use `malloc` **I'm sure** that that memory must be freed. Many people think (I saw too many question on that kind of error) that `strdup` does some kind of magic and, without reading the doc, spreading memory leak around the world. About citation: probably you are lucky to not bother about multi platform poorly equipped application/platforms as other must think on.

Comment: @0andriy Finally: I've never said you to do so, do what you want..... if you are aware of all constrains.

Comment: Okay, thanks for elaborating your point. I'll continue blaming some stupid SDKs and use *standard* (what users are using) functions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to allocate `link->concept` and `link->sentence` (see line 7). Or declare them as arrays (`char concept[100]` instead of `char *concept`)

Important: Please always use `strncpy` instead of `strcpy`.

```
void insert(char *concept, char *sentence, int timesUsed, char learnedFrom[5]) 
{
    int flag = 0, temp; 

    struct cList *link = (struct cList*) malloc(sizeof(struct cList));

    // Add these:
    link->concept = malloc...
    link->sentence = malloc...

    if(link!=NULL)
    {
        strcpy(link->concept,concept); //this is where the stack overflow happens first.
        strcpy(link->sentence,sentence);
        link->timesUsed = timesUsed;
        strcpy(link->learnedFrom,learnedFrom);

        link->next = head;
        head = link;

        temp = rand()%5;
        if(temp==0)
            printf("3B$ It sure is great to know everything about %s.\n", concept);
        else if(temp==1)
            printf("3B$ This information about %s is quite interesting.", concept);
        else if(temp==2)
            printf("3B$ I have to admit, learning about %s is much more interesting than it seems.", concept);
        else if(temp==3)
            printf("3B$ Learning about %s wasn't even a challenge.", concept);
        else if(temp==4)
            printf("3B$ Wow, learning about %s was so exciting!", concept);
    }
    else
        printf("3B$ Memory not available!!!\n");
}
```

Comment: Alright, thank you everyone for helping me figure this out.
Much apreciation <3

Comment: Sorry, but I cannot agree with your blanket recommendation to avoid `strcpy()` in favor of `strncpy()`.  One absolutely must be certain to avoid overrunning the bounds of the target array, but using `strncpy()` to do that has its own set of associated problems.  `strncpy()` is not a cure-all.

Answer (score 0):

The `concept` and `sentence` pointers in your allocated structure have not been initialized.  So when you use `strcpy`, you are dereferencing an uninitialized pointer.  This invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) which in this case causes the program to crash.

What you need to do is to allocate space for these pointers as well, then perform the copy:

```
link->concept = malloc(strlen(concept) + 1);
strcpy(link->concept,concept);
```

You can also do this in one step with `strdup`:

```
link->concept = strdup(concept);
```